# How do you insert a number in between two adjacent numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

How would you **1)** insert 1's between any two adjacent 5's? and then **2)** insert a value into the second list at the same index as the 1 that was inserted into the first list?

For example,

```
list1 = [  5,   1,   5,   5,   5,   1,  etc.]
```

would become

```
list1 = [  5,   1,   5,   1,   5,   1,   5,   1,  etc.]
```

And,

```
list2 = [ val, val, val, val, val, val, etc.]
```

would become

```
list2 = [ val, val, val, Nval, val, Nval, etc.]
```

(Nval up above = the added value)

I'm a beginner so help is greatly appreciated :O)

Comment: That sounds like *REALLY* specific algorithm... You should describe it using pseudo-code and only then implement it carefully, by iterating your original list

Comment: Hopefully I explained this clearly. Just to clarify -- I first need to insert the item based of what would come after/before it, THEN I would need to insert a value into the second list at the same index.

Comment: Then you just need to look into `list1[i-1]` and `list1[i+1]`, in order to make a decision

Comment: So you want to insert 1's between any two adjacent 5's?

Comment: Yes exactly! and then insert a value in the second list at the same index

Comment: @ddog you should restate your problem like that

Comment: Ok, I will, thank you!  @OlivierMelançon

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 My question was "How to insert a number in between two adjacent numbers". I updated the title and the body section so that it's more obvious/clear what my question is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look at pairs of consecutive values. To do that, let's pair the list with the last item cut off (`list[:-1]`) with again the list, but with the first item cut off (`list[1:]`). (The slice notation used here is [being introduced in the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/674064).)

```
zip(list1[:-1], list1[1:])
```

(The `zip` function turns a pair of sequences into a sequence of pairs and is introduced [here in the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) and [documented here](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).)

Let's see which these pairs are `(5, 5)`:

```
[pair == (5, 5) for pair in zip(list1[:-1], list1[1:])]
```

The feature used here is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), a way of writing a (new) list by giving a rule to construct it from an existing iterable.

What are the indices of these pairs? Let's number them with `enumerate`:

```
[n for (n, pair) in enumerate(zip(list1[:-1], list1[1:])) if pair == (5, 5)]
```

This is another list comprehension, this time with a condition for the elements (a "predicate"). Note that `enumerate` returns pairs of numbers and values (which are our original pairs), and that we use implicit unpacking to get them into the loop variables `n` and `pair` respectively.

`list.insert(i, new_value)` takes the index *after* which the new value shall be inserted. Thus to find the positions where to insert into the original list (and into list2), we need to add `1` to the pair indices:

```
idxs = [n + 1 for (n, pair) in enumerate(zip(list1[:-1], list1[1:])) if pair == (5, 5)]

for i in reversed(idxs):
    list1.insert(idxs, 1)
    list2.insert(idxs, 'Nval')
```

(We insert in reverse order, so as to not move the pairs between which we have yet to insert.)

Answer (score 1):

You can recover the insertion indices with a single list comprehension. You are looking for indices `i` such that `5 == list1[i-1] == list1[i]`.

You then need to insert in decreasing order of indices.

```
list1 = [5,   1,   5,   5,   5,   1]
list2 = [val, val, val, val, val, val] 

indices = [i for i in range(1, len(list1)) if 5 == list1[i-1] == list1[i]]

for i in reversed(indices):
    list1.insert(i, 1)
    list2.insert(i, Nval)

print(list1) # [5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1]
print(list2) # [val, val, val, Nval, val, Nval, val, val]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
list1 = [5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1]
copied = iter(['val' for _ in list1])
grouped = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(list1)]
new_result = [list(b) if a != 5 else [[5, 1] if c < len(b) - 1 else [5] for c, _ in enumerate(b)] for a, b in grouped]
final_result = [[i] if not isinstance(i, list) else i for b in new_result for i in b]
new_copied = [[next(copied)] if len(i) == 1 else [next(copied), 'Nval'] for i in final_result]
list2, list2_copied = list(itertools.chain(*final_result)), list(itertools.chain(*new_copied))
```

Output:

```
[5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1]
['val', 'val', 'val', 'Nval', 'val', 'Nval', 'val', 'val']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [5,1,5,5,5,1,5,5,1,5,5,5,5]
list2 = []

templist = []

for idx,val in enumerate(list1):
    if (idx+1) <= (len(list1)-1):
        if list1[idx+1] == 5 and list1[idx] == 5:
            templist.append(val)
            templist.append(1)
            list2.append(val)
            list2.append(42)
        else:
            templist.append(val)
            list2.append(val)
```

Gives me as output:

```
templist [5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1]
list2 [5, 1, 5, 42, 5, 42, 5, 1, 5, 42, 5, 1, 5, 42, 5, 42, 5, 42]
```

And to finish off:
`list1 = templist`

Answer (score 0):

One-line solution based on `zip` and `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

new_val = 10  # value to use for list2 (Nval)
new_list1 = []
new_list2 = []
reduce(lambda x, y: ((y[0] == 5 and x == 5) and (new_list1.append(1) or new_list2.append(new_val))) or
                     new_list1.append(y[0]) or new_list2.append(y[1]) or y[0],
         zip(list1, list2), (None, new_list1, new_list2))
```